# Injecting config values into a Spring Boot application, without using @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I want to inject configuration data into a Spring Boot application. I looked at @Value and this would be perfect but the format of the text is not appropriate for my use case (I want the format to be backward compatible with our current implementation in JEE which will sit alongside our SpringBoot implementation and there is a lot of code that uses this approach at the moment).

So instead of saying @Configuration("${somevalue}") and the config being injected I want to say @Configuration("somevalue") and it still be injected rather than it just putting the "somevalue" text in the variable.

Where Configuration is an alias of @Value, like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Value("")
public @interface Configuration {
    @AliasFor(annotation=Value.class, attribute="value")
    String value() default "";
}
```

I did try changing the pre and post suffixes for the placeholder so they were "" but this resulted in SpringBoot not starting up at all.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    p.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    p.setPlaceholderPrefix("");
    p.setPlaceholderSuffix("");
    p.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
    return p;
}
```

I also tried changing the Annotation at runtime so that I scan the classpath and change all the Annotations without ${...} to ${...}, but that's not working either because the Proxy handler value changes each time you do a class lookup which means that you change the instance you are looking at but NOT the instance that Spring uses.

So I then thought I would have my own @Value implementation, to be used like this:

```
@RestController
public class PingResource {

    @Inject
    public PingResource(@Configuration("someValue") String someValue) {
       ...
    }
}
```

With a Bean producer like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationProducer {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public String getString(final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
      ....
    }
}
```

But the qualifiers in Spring don't look like they support Annotations so it doesn't find the bean, I get this exception:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@bob.Configuration(value=someValue)}
```

If I take the Annotation off the parameter then it finds the bean factory and all is well...apart from I don't know what config value I should be injecting because there is no annotation present to tell me.

So bit stuck, I have looked at the Spring code to see how it implements @Value to see if I could recreate that, but thats a rats nest of pain to understand.

Any help or advise where to look next to solve this issue, it feels like I am very close but just missing some Spring magic that I am not aware of.

Thanks very much

Comment: You could use reflection to change field values in spring beans. Is that something that would work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that using:

    InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);  
    Field f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");  
    f.setAccessible(true);  
    Map<String, Object> memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);  
    memberValues.put(key, newValue);  
  
And it works in that if you get the Annotation value using the same "getDeclaredConstructors()" return varriable. But when you do it again, the change is lost. I think its becuase the Proxy value is different each time you do a lookup so any changes are lost.

Comment: You can use Springs application context to access all spring beans and then manipulate them. for (String bean : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) ... and then access them individually. Would only work for fields in spring beans though

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something, you could try that:

My annotation class:

```
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotation{

    String value();

}
```

Then I use an Injector class to inject all values into spring beans.

```
@Component
public class Injector {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Injector.class.getName());

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public Injector(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void inject() {

        for (String bean : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {

            for (Field field : applicationContext.getBean(bean).getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class)) {
                    // Instantiate Annotation Values
                    SomeAnnotationvalue value = field.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);

                    // Instantiate Resource
                    String resource = ...

                    // Set accessibility of field
                    field.setAccessible(true);

                    try {
                        // Set Value to field
                        field.set(applicationContext.getBean(bean), resource);

                        // Reverse setting accessibility
                        field.setAccessible(false);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | MissingResourceException e) {
                        logger.error("Error while trying to inject resources into bean {}: {}", bean, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

You would need to call this on application start.

Note: This only works if your annotated fields are a Spring Bean (@Service, @Component, @Controller, @Repository, etc...)

Then an in class example would look like this:

```
@SomeAnnotation("some.property.value")
private String propertyValue
```